# Problemas con importacion de EM6 con modulo de mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, webpack, importación

Hola estoy levantando un back y estoy teniendo problemas con la importación de los modelos y los schemas de mongoose... y me esta sacando de quicio , una de mis opciones es ingresarle un bundler pero me parece a su vez muy extraño que no quiera asumir la importación de em6 siendo que al levantar el servidor y la base de datos no se quejo la consola ... en el momento que levante las rutas y los modelos empezó a salirme este cartel...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien podría iluminarme y decirme que opciones tengo aparte de suicidarme.

Si alguien esta leyendo esto ya le implemente al package.json la opción "type" : "module" y aun así no funciona la versión de mi node es 14.17.0

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido@. Las publicaciones que no contienen el codigo en una imagen , no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Por favor, revisa [como hacer un pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edita tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte. Gracias

Comment: la segunda imagen muestra el codigo de como importe y exporte ese modulo, no se llega a ver ?

Comment: @GabrielCaballero [Esta es una guía (_Un fragmento de código vale más que mil imágenes_)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976) de por qué hay que evitar compartir código y mensajes de excepción como imagen.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve revisando tu codigo y el error es debido a que estas intentando importar un 'CommondJS' que al espanol serian modulos comunes que los usuarios de nodeJS tienden a utilizar y es por ello que sus importanciones son mas sencillas, para importar este modulo lo unico que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente:

```
// Using ES6 imports
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
```

y para importar el esquema como tal lo que puedes hacer es instanciar el mongoose

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

De esta manera no obtendras el error, este error es debido a esto y se da en las nuevas versiones de nodeJS, si tienes dudas respecto a esto siempre puedes consultar la documentacion de node o simplemente te recomiendo leer el siguiente articulo donde se explica un poco mas de lo sucedido:
[Blog de referencia](https://simonplend.com/node-js-now-supports-named-imports-from-commonjs-modules-but-what-does-that-mean/)

Comment: Hola, estuve revisando la documentacion en como hacer los exports y estos se pueden hacer de varias maneras, te dejo un ejemplo que los creadores de mongoose dan en la propia documentacion, tal vez con esto te des una idea como implementarla en tu proyecto
[ejemplo](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/examples/schema/schema.js)